# Traefik Docker hot reload configuration

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to update my traefik.yml from outside, and hope that the Traefik container instance which is setup via docker-compose.yml. But it turns out it didn't work.

I've mapped traefik.yml into the instance:

```
volumes:
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
```

but it does not seems to auto reload on file update.

I've tried to shell into the container and check if the file is updated, and it seems to be updated fine.

How can I make autoreload work in Docker?

Comment: Hi James. So far the dynamic configuration are about: frontends, backends, servers and HTTPS Certificates. You need to enable `watch=true` in your config to work. Is it help you? Best regards.

Comment: hi @MarcoBlos, yes ive tried with ```watch=true``` below ```[file]``` and it did not work

Comment: This is an old topic, but remember that when you bind mount a file into a container what you actually mount is the inode that the filename references. Most text editors perform atomic writes which means that while the filename stays the same the inode is changed. This means that the file mounted into your container might not be in sync with what you see on the host. The work around is to only ever bind-mount directories instead of filenames.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like traefik is only able to watch frontend, backend rules and https certificates from changing configs.

From the docs:

> To enable the file backend, you must either pass the --file option to the Træfik binary or put the [file] section (with or without inner settings) in the configuration file.
>   The configuration file allows managing both backends/frontends and HTTPS certificates (which are not Let's Encrypt certificates generated through Træfik).

You need to add an additional

```
[file]
watch = true
```

to enable file watching and dynamic configuration

Comment: sorry i did mentioned in comments , it didnt work in docker

Comment: For the docker provider it works the same. Just add to your traefik.toml configuration file:

[docker]
watch = true

Answer (score 0):

Traefik dont support hot reloading for entrypoints.

It's not a problem for http services if you define 80/443 ports and route via http rules, but if you would like to add tcp service you must restart traefik with dropping all active connections

I tried to deploy traefik inside docker swarm with file based and label based configuration, but sending a SIGHUP to traefik kills traefik with dropping all connections

Only one solution for tcp based services is predefined range of tcp entrypoints, e.g

```
 entrypoint_tcp_4000:
 entrypoint_tcp_4001:
 entrypoint_tcp_4002:
...
 entrypoint_tcp_4050:
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).